# Is it valid to write irrational number written as an infinite sum of rational number?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I would like to know why if it is not valid. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $f(x)=0$ is a solution.

Comment: @Martin R I'm sorry, I wrote in picture since I didn't have a labtop. Should I delete this post?

Comment: @Arthur Can you elaborate more? I'm don't see why that is significant.

Comment: Mostly it looks good. To be careful, you should show that $f(1/b) \neq 0$. Because when you say "this implies $f(a)=a$", you are implicitly dividing both sides by $f(1/b)$

Comment: @NazimJ Do I still need to show that when I assumed a/b to be rational?

Comment: If $x\geq0$, then there is $y$ such that $y^2=x$. Then $f(x)=f(y^2)=f(y)^2\geq0$. So, $f$ is non-negative on the non-negative numbers. Then if $x\geq y$, then $f(x)=f(x-y+y)=f(x-y)+f(y)\geq f(y)$, since $f(x-y)\geq0$ for $x-y$ being non-negative. Use that $f$ is monotonic to finish. Observe that the value $f(a)$ at an irrational value $a$ will have to be sandwiched between the values at all rationals $r,s$ wish $r<a<s$. So, $r=f(r)\leq f(a)\leq f(s)=s$. This forces $f(a)=a$ by taking limits with $r,s\to a$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423492/42969 for a comprehensive overview of the Cauchy functional equation.

Comment: Yes you can write that $r =\sum \frac {a_i}{10^i}$ but we can not assume that $f(\sum\frac{a_i}{10^i}) = \sum f(\frac {a_i}{10^i})$ for infinite sums.

Comment: The first sentence on your piece of paper (assuming you mean $x$ when you say $r$) is directly contradicted by the solution $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @fleablood Why is that? Since I showed that f(rational) = rational, can't I just sum all the rationals again after applying the function?

Comment: @Mardia Because that is not a sum. It is a sum plus a limit, a series. In [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4522477/is-it-valid-to-write-irrational-number-written-as-an-infinite-sum-of-rational-nu#comment9500804_4522477) you can see how to finish the argument.

Comment: @Arthur You are right. I must have missed an important information when I wrote down the question. This is a question 17 on chapter 2 of spivaks.

Comment: "can't I just sum all the rationals again after applying the function"  Absolutely not.  You only know it for 2 term sums and by induction you can show it for any $n$ terms sums but you can't ever get to infinity by doing things one step at a time.  Infinite sums are tricky and the common sense rules of rearranging and "adding just one more" simply don't apply.  This is a consequence of the key difference between rational and irrational numbers.  There's too much to go into in a comment but no, you just can't do that.

Comment: And what @user85667 said....  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_i$ although it is written to *look* like an infinite sum is actually $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n b_i$.  There is no such thing as "infinite sums"  only limits of infinite sequences of values (which in turn may be finite sums).  Now it is true that $f(\sum^n b_i) = \sum^n f(b_i)$ for all $n$ and all $b_i$ but it does not follow that $f(\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum^nb_i)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum^n f(b_i)$.

Comment: @user85667 "In this comment you can see how to finish the argument." But that is assuming $f$ is continuous.  We can show it is true for all reals if we assume $f$ is continuous.  But if $f$ is not continuous, we can use the multiplicative property to show it is true for all algebraic numbers, but I don't think we can every prove it for trancendental numbers.  In fact I think we can prove $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is algebraic and $f(x)=0$ otherwise will qualify.

Comment: @fleablood No, in the comment it is proven that $f$ is monotonic and that is enough to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write an irrational number as a sum of rationals. Then the last step in your argument depends on knowing that the function $f$ is continuous.

If you know that, then  knowing that addition is preserved you can show $f(x) = cx$ for some constant $c$.

This is a well studied problem: see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation

I don't know whether assuming that the function preserves multiplication too suffices to get the continuity.

Comment: I think a reasonable confusion is that if $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ and by induction that would mean $f(\sum_{k=1}^n x_i) = \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_i)$ then we wouldn't it be valid so say $f(\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_i) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty f(x_i)$. That is the OPs error.  And the general "infinite sums are tricky! always be careful" applies.  But in more detail.  Induction implies that the property holds for all *finite* sums.  But you can not get to infinity by any number of *inductive* steps so does not hold for infinite sums.  Details and counter examples .... well, we can go on forever.

Comment: @fleablood Haven't started analysis yet so I don't see why it is wrong here since to me it just seems like a tautology in this case but I appreciate it very much. Thank you!

Comment: As a simple example of where it can fail, consider $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is rational, and $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is irrational. For all of the finite sums $\sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i) = \sum_{i = 0}^N 0 = 0 = f(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i)$, but clearly in the limit you get $f(x) = 1 \neq 0 = \sum_{i=0}^\infty f(x_i)$.

Comment: @ConMan But this function doesn't satisfy the f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y).

Comment: It doesn't, I was just using it as an example of how "true for all finite $N$" and "true in the limit as $N$ goes to infinity" aren't always consistent.